# There is no implicit reference conversion from 'dungGenerator.Room' to 'System.IComparable

Tags: c#, templates, compareto, icomparable

okay, i followed many tutorial to make it work but i never found a solution.

i have this function in a static class:

```
        public static bool isDifferent<T>(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) where T : IComparable
    {
        foreach (T item1 in list1)
        {
            bool different = false;
            foreach (T item2 in list2)
            {
                if (item2.CompareTo(item1) != 0)
                    different = true;
                else
                {
                    different = false;
                    break;//fuck yes i will use a break
                }
            }
            if (different)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

it work well with list of int
but now i want to compare a list of a custom class named room.

my class declaration have all he need : public class Room : IComparable

and i added the CompareTo function.

```
        public int CompareTo(Room other)
    {
        if (other == null) return 1;

        if (Methods.isDifferent(doors, other.doors))
            return 1;
        else 
            return 0;

    }
```

so, each room have a list of hallway id and this the only value i need to compare.

i followed many tutorial and they seems to have the same structure as mine.

Comment: sounds like a crappy problem to be facing

Comment: i know, i dont understand why the exemple i found on the net work while they are basicly the same as this

Comment: @Jonesy When there is Room in my dungGenerator, I eat.

Comment: Could you post the code where the exception is thrown from?

Comment: if(Methods.isDifferent(rooms, hallways[i].rooms))

Comment: in my class hallway i call this to scan Doors who need to update their ID with the new path group.

Comment: What is the exact line where you declare `Room`? As your code is currently, I don't understand how it even compiles

Comment: In the future you should probably post code exactly in the question. When you wrote "Room : IComparable", you left off the key part!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `Room` implements `IComparable<Room>`, which is not the same interface as `IComparable`. You should probably update your method to:

```
public static bool isDifferent<T>(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) where T : IComparable<T>
```

Comment: thanks! it worked, so i was only missing a really small part.

Answer (score 1):

From you question, i can deduce that you implement the interface IComparable<**Room**>.

However, this interface *IComparable<T>* is not assignable to *IComparable*.

Implement *IComparable*, which declares the method "public int CompareTo(**object** other)".

Comment: public class Room : IComparable<Room>
{
        public List<int> doors;
        public int CompareTo(Room other)
        {
            if (other == null) return 1;

            if (Methods.isDifferent(doors, other.doors))
                return 1;
            else 
                return 0;

        }
}

Comment: @CédricRaymond, as i said, i deduced this already (and so did Ben in his answer, too...)

Comment: sorry i did not notice the <Room>
your answer was also good but his was clearer =p

Comment: i also had to edit my question for the same reason.
And i dont understand why someone downvoted my question.
It was a legit question

Comment: I have no idea about the downvote too. It is common to confuse IComparer<T> and IComparer (even in code review or discussion amongst peers, where you would just say something like "this type implements IComparer" and everybody starts asking "Which one, the generic or non-generic?" ;) )